# More than one PermissionEvaluator in the same app

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have a custom PermissionEvaluator based on our own acl system. I would like to add another PermissionEvaluator implementation. That can conflict with the existing PermissionEvaluator. How can I avoid that? Introduce some kind of aggregation mechanism for both PermissionEvaluators? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your exception ? send stacktrace

Answer (score 9):

So I found a solution to this problem. I created

```
public class EvaluatorsAggregator
    implements PermissionEvaluator
{

  private List<PermissionEvaluator> evaluators;

  public EvaluatorsAggregator(List<PermissionEvaluator> evaluators)
  {
    super();
    this.evaluators = evaluators;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean hasPermission(Authentication authentication, Object targetDomainObject, Object permission)
  {
    return evaluators.stream()
        .map(ev -> ev.hasPermission(authentication, targetDomainObject, permission))
        .reduce(Boolean::logicalOr)
        .orElse(false);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean hasPermission(
      Authentication authentication,
      Serializable targetId,
      String targetType,
      Object permission)
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Then in the config file I added all the needed evaluators:

```
@Configuration
@Lazy(true)
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class Config
{

  @Autowired
  Repository repository1;

  @Autowired
  Repository repository2;

  @Bean
  public PermissionEvaluator permissionEvaluator()
  {
    List<PermissionEvaluator> evaluators = new ArrayList<>();
    evaluators.add(new PermissionEvaluator1(repository1));
    evaluators.add(new PermissionEvaluator2(repository2));
    return new EvaluatorsAggregator(evaluators);
  }
}
```

Maybe this can help somebody.

Comment: Instead of implementing a full blown CoR, you can also do a lookup and based on the targetDomainObject you determine the right Bean for your permission eval -> `ev.supports(targetDomainObject)`